# Can I rough in an exterior light without cutting into the siding?

Tags: electrical, lighting, exterior, rough-in

I have my interior wall exposed and would like to rough in some outdoor lights without actually cutting into the exterior siding right now. I plan on replacing the siding this summer.

Is this possible? Should I do it this way? What sort of boxes would I use for this? New work?

[image]

Comment: So long as you trust your locating ability :-), no reason not to mount a box and wiring now.  I'd recommend not connecting any wires to a hot source until you're ready to mount fixtures on the exterior.

Comment: I think if you used something the mark the location of the box that's visible from the exterior you'd be ok. Something like a machine screw/bolt through the siding, covered with a bit of silicone or something. Otherwise, how would you accurately locate the roughed-in box without stripping all the siding?

Comment: If you use an old work box you could do it. Nailing a box behind the sheeting would leave to large of a gap when the new siding is put in unless an extension ring is used.